# lock pdf with itext after sign

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I need to lock a pdf after applying a signature, I need the output file to look like this one:

[locked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsQpy.png)

as you can see it says "locked by signature",

I tried adding the lock like this when I get the pdf signature appearance:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance pdfAppearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
pdfAppearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
```

but all I have got in return is this:

[mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDCCc.png)

only a message that says "no changes allowed",

**what should I add in the process to mark the PDF to not be able to receive more signatures nor changes?**

Comment: Your code adds a *certification signature* (which must be the first AcroForm signature of a document) to set the MDP level to no-changes allowed. What you want is a regular *approval signature* with a **Lock** dictionary to set the MDP level to no-changes-allowed. The resulting permissions are the same as long as the PDF viewer supports PDF-2.0. Older viewers may ignore the mechanism you want. For details have a look at the iText eBook [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf) section 2.5.5: Locking fields and documents after signing

Comment: @mkl thnx for the link but still there in there book, it's not clear for me :(

Comment: Have you tried @Lonzak's answer? It represents one way of creating a **Lock** dictionary. Depending on the exact iText version you use there may or may not be easier ways.

Comment: @mkl couldn't try @ Lonzak, but your other answer worked just fine a million thnx! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Signature Locking With Current iText 5 Versions

[@Lontak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72487619/1729265) demonstrates how one can add a signature lock dictionary using low-level classes. This in particular is of interest for early iText versions (before 5.3.2) and forks of them. Newer iText versions offer a dedicated higher level class modelling signature lock dictionaries and support for them while signing.

Signature **Lock** dictionaries are modelled by the `PdfSigLockDictionary` class in current iText 5 versions.

If you want to create a locking signature instead of a certification signature (look below, though), you can do so by replacing your

```java
pdfAppearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
```

by

```java
PdfSigLockDictionary pdfSigLockDictionary = new PdfSigLockDictionary(LockPermissions.NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
pdfAppearance.setFieldLockDict(pdfSigLockDictionary);
```

*([CreateLockingSignature](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/CreateLockingSignature.java#L71) test `signWithLockNoChangesAllowed`)*

#### Should You Replace Certification by Locking?

Your question sounds like someone requires you to use locking instead of certification to set the MDP level to no-changes-allowed.

Objectively, though, this makes sense only if the signature in question is not the first signature of a PDF, because a certification signature - if present at all - must be the first signature of a document.

As long as your signature is the first (and due to no-changes-allowed the only) signature of the document, you should set the MDP level by means of certification because certification has already been defined in ISO 32000-1 while document locking  has been added in ISO 32000-2 (before ISO 32000-2 was published, document locking was only available as an Adobe extension to ISO 32000-1). Support for ISO 32000-2 is somewhat limited, many PDF related products still are based on ISO 32000-1 (or even earlier PDF references). Thus, your document locking is more likely to be ignored by PDF processors than the certification.

Comment: this worked but had to upgrade to itext 5.5.7 thnx @mkl

Answer (score 0):

What iText Version are you using?
Something along these lines should work:

```
//get the field item of your sig field
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
Item item = acroFields.getFieldItem(sigFieldName);
PdfDictionary data = item.getValue(0);

//create lock dict
PdfDictionary lockDict = new PdfDictionary();
lockDict.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.SIGFIELDLOCK);
//action parameter is mandatory
lockDict.put(PdfName.ACTION, PdfName.ALL);
//OR lockDict.put(PdfName.ACTION, PdfName.INCLUDE);
//OR lockDict.put(PdfName.ACTION, PdfName.EXCLUDE);
lockDict.put(PdfName.P, new PdfNumber(1 || 2 || 3);
    
//add as indirect object
PRIndirectReference ref = reader.addPdfObject(lockDict);
data.put(PdfName.LOCK, ref);
```

Depending on the iText version some keys might not be there (yet). In this case define them for yourself:

```
PdfName ACTION = new PdfName("Action");
PdfName ALL = new PdfName("All");
PdfName EXCLUDE = new PdfName("Exclude");
PdfName INCLUDE = new PdfName("Include");
PdfName SIGFIELDLOCK = new PdfName("SigFieldLock");
```